# UISegmentedControl selection not updating before animation

Tags: ios

I have a UISegmentedControl that is shown/hide like a modal window. Initially it does not have a selected segment. In IB, the Value Changed event is wired to the method - (IBAction)cardClassificationChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender. Here is that method:

```
- (IBAction)cardClassificationChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%d", sender.selectedSegmentIndex);
    // block for updating the categorization of current card asynchronously
    [self.cardActionSheet hideWithAnimation];
}
```

If I comment out the last line (the call to -hideWithAnimation), the selection changes as expected, everything works. However, with the call to that animation method, the UISegmentedControl selection will not visually change before the animation. Here is the hideWithAnimation method:

```
- (void)hideWithAnimation
{
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.type = kCATransitionFade;
    animation.duration = globalAnimationLength;
    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];

    self.hidden = YES;
}
```

The next time this view appears (from a touch gesture), the UISegmentedControl will have the correct segment selected though.

It seems like I should not have to call setNeedsDisplay for the UISegmentedControl, but even when I experiment with it in the cardClassificationChanged method or the hideWithAnimation method, it does not refresh.

I'm obviously missing something related to the UI update, what do I need to call to update the UISegmentedControl selection before the animation?

Comment: The method `-hideWithAnimation` is never called at `-cardClassificationChanged:`, `-hideCardActionSheet:` is called instead. Could you please check the copied code and fix it ?

Comment: You're right, sorry for the confusion. -hideCardActionSheet has some other logic/processing, then calls -hideWithAnimation. I will update when I'm able to get back to that machine. For now, there are not any problems with the animations or logic inside of cardClassificationChanged, my issue is that the UISegmentedControl does not visually update to reflect the selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you should use UIKit animations for fading out your control. Try the following code

```
- (void)hideWithAnimation
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                 animations:^{
                     self.alpha = 0.;
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     self.alpha = 1.;
                     self.hidden = YES;
                 }];
}
```

Comment: Using this block-based animation solved the issue, and is more modern code :) Thank you very much. Any reference or comment you could provide as to why the UISegmentedControl does not update with the CATransition approach would be appreciated (for my own understanding).

Comment: @afalls It must be thread-related, if you call the animation with `[self performSelector:@selector(hideWithAnimation:)
               withObject:sender
                 afterDelay:0];` (from the main thread of course, the key is the delay, even if it is zero) it works fine with `CATransition`